# Firebase Analytics missing random events

Tags: swift, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics to send custom events from my iOS apps.
I've imported the framework with SPM and sending the events with:

```
Analytics.logEvent(name, parameters: parameters)
```

I enabled from my Xcode scheme these args: 
*-FIRAnalyticsVerboseLoggingEnabled

-FIRDebugEnabled*

So I'm able to see the events in the **DebugView** console. 
The problem is that from the Xcode console I see the events as logged but some of these events are randomly missing from the **DebugView** and from the *intraday* export into **BigQuery**. <-- So the issue is not with the DebugView data not being 100% reliable, we are missing some important events here.

From the Xcode logs I see the event as logged and sent:

```
2022-02-14 18:33:03.035860+0100 AppName[36500:540833] 8.12.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: ce_paywall_view, {
```

And Then:

```
Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
```

Full log: https://gist.github.com/DanielZanchi/8aa0ae815adaea7420ce9dc3e2ac85a0

Comment: Hello, Firebase Analytics relies on GA4. The docs state that it can take up to 48h for the data to be propagated across all the reports. Have you waited that long? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790?hl=en

Comment: How could the BigQuery work that way. The export is set as a stream (intraday) and daily. If I don't see the events in the daily table it means that the event is not logged properly.